# How does a stream work with a callback using Azure Blob createReadStream?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a function that successfully returns a stream object to the calling function containing a blob I need from Azure Storage:

```
module.exports.readFileToStream = function(fileSpec, callback){

  return blobService.createReadStream(fileSpec.container, fileSpec.file, function(err, results){

    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      callback(err);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
    callback(null, results);

  });
```

}

My issue is that I need to get the file's metadata as returned by that callback, but there seems to be no way to access that callback from outside the function when the stream is used.

This works as expected, the file is downloaded:

```
function downloadFile(req, res){

  var fileSpec = {container: 'aaa', file: 'bbb'};

  var stream = .readFileToStream(fileSpec);

  stream.pipe(res);

}
```

This doesn't work, there are no error messages and the response is seemingly never called.

```
  let stream = storage.readFileToStream(fileSpec, function(err, results){

    if(err){
      res.status(400).send({"message": "could not retrieve file"});
      return;
    }

    stream.pipe(res);

  });
```

How can I access this callback along with the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend you to use `getBlobToStream`. It allows you to write `stream` to `res` directly and you can access the blob `results` as well.

readFileToStream method.

```
module.exports.readFileToStream = function(fileSpec,res){

    blobService.getBlobToStream(fileSpec.container, fileSpec.file, res, function(err, results){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send({"message": "could not retrieve file"});
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
    }
  });
}
```

downloadFile method.

```
function downloadFile(req, res){

    var fileSpec = {container: container, file: path};

    storage.readFileToStream(fileSpec,res);
}
```

Any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks, this works when the file is there but I get a node.js error "Can't set headers after they are sent." when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Graham Did you specify any on error event on the stream?

Comment: Yes, I did set the error event on the stream but (like my other question) it detects both the error and sends the response stream.

Comment: @Graham That is the problem. `getBlobToStream` has its own callback to handle error, if you add error event on the stream,  the callback will also be called after the error event sends the response. So callback of `getBlobToStream` is good enough to handle error, no need to use error event. In your other question, we have to use error event because `createReadStream` doesn't handle `file not exist` error in its own callback.

Comment: I'm also setting custom headers on the response, and those seem to be getting in the way.  I'll either edit this question or start a new one for that issue.

Comment: @Graham OK, I will follow up. If you choose to open a new issue, you could accept my solutions to these problems for others to refer.

Comment: It came down to not having a return statement after the error handling in the callback.  The callback error handling wasn't terminating the thread, and my custom headers were then written to a response that had already been sent back with a 400.  Thanks again!